TensorFlow 2 Unable to recognize CPU physical device
i'm encountering an error related to distributed training with TensorFlow CPU-only version. The error message provided
InvalidArgumentError: /job:worker/replica:0/task:1/device:CPU:0 unknown device

and it suggests that TensorFlow is unable to recognize the CPU device.
My code :
if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()
elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":
    with tf.device("/job:worker/task:%d/cpu:0" % FLAGS.task_index):
      model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            ...
        ])

Is there any way for the CPU to be recognized without rebuilding TensorFlow, as I have already tried but still cannot? Please help.
I've tried to check with these code
import tensorflow as tf
print("CPU count:", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('CPU')))
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())


and the results:
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 18350198767997648811
xla_global_id: -1
]

